# Finding string in txt file and displaying a line

Tags: c

Hey fellas working on a code here and I'am kinda lost.

```
int main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    struct info
    {
        char name[15];
        char surename[15];
        char gender[15];
        char education[15];

    } info;

    char c;
    int i, j, a;
    struct info sem;

  beginning:

    scanf("%d", &a);

if(a==1)
{
fp = fopen("info.txt", "r");
     for(i=0;!feof(fp);i++)
 {   fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s", 
                sem.name,
                sem.surname,
                sem.gender,
                sem.education,);
                printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n",
                sem.name,
                sem.surname,
                sem.gender,
                sem.education,);
     }   
       fclose(fp);
  goto beginning;
    }
   if (a == 2)

    {
        FILE *fp = fopen("info.txt", "r");
        char tmp[256] = { 0x0 };
        while (fp != NULL && fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), fp) != NULL)

        {

            if (strstr(tmp, "bachelors"))

                /* Code works fine until this part */

                fprintf(fp, "\n%s %s %s %s %s %s",
                        sem.name, sem.surname, sem.gender, sem.education,);

        }
        if (fp != NULL)
            fclose(fp);
        goto beginning;
    }
```

After finding string "bachelor" it should printf rest of the line where it found it, in this case name, surname etc etc of a user found with bachelor degree, yet it doesnt, if anyone could point out my mistake, id be very greatful!

Comment: It looks like you're not assigning anything to `sem` but you're printing `sem` members expecting it to contain something.

Comment: No, not the dreaded `goto`!

Comment: sorry managed to forget to add that code part as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:
1. Revise on structures
2. Get rid of `GOTO` in your code (its a bad programming standard)
3. proper code indentation

Go through the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct info
    {
        char name[15];
        char surname[15];
        char gender[15];
        char education[15];

    } sem;

    FILE *fp=NULL;
    int i, a;
    char tmp[256] = {0x0};

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter the value\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        if((fp = fopen("info.txt", "r")) != NULL)
        {

            switch(a)       // assuming your code is just an snippet and actual code has more than 2 conditions
            {               // use if-else if just 2 condition checks

                case 0:
                        exit(0);        // quit the program

                case 1: 

                    for(i=0;!feof(fp);i++)
                    {
                        fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s", sem.name, sem.surname, sem.gender, sem.education);
                        printf("%s, %s, %s, %s\n",sem.name,sem.surname,sem.gender,sem.education);
                    }   

                    break;

                case 2:

                    while (fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), fp) != NULL)
                    {
                        if (strstr(tmp, "bachelors"))
                        {
                            /* Code works fine until this part */
                            fprintf(fp, "\n%s %s %s %s", sem.name, sem.surname, sem.gender, sem.education);                         
                        }   
                    }

                    break;

                default:    printf("Default statement");                                        
            }

            fclose(fp);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (fgets(tmp, sizeof(tmp), fp) != NULL)` also does not seem required you could do just a `fgets` and proceed